# Conditional operator (ternary operator) with anonymous function

Tags: java

I want to do some stuff in a anonymous function nested in a conditional operator:

```
import javakara.JavaKaraProgram;

public class A4C extends JavaKaraProgram {
  public void myProgram() {
    while (!kara.onLeaf()) {
        boolean m = kara.treeFront() ? (()->{
            //content of function
            }):false;
    }
  }
}
```

kara.treeFront() returns a boolean
I figured i have to make the conditional operator result in a variable.

My current error message is:

```
   path/a4c.java:6: error: incompatible types: bad type in conditional expression
        boolean m = kara.treeFront() ? (()->{
                                        ^
        boolean is not a functional interface
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to assign a boolean, and `(()->{})` is not a boolean. Unless you can show more code, there probably isn't any good reason to do this, just declare a normal method, and call that with the inputs it needs, to yield the boolean it should produce.

Comment: There is no good reason to use a function here.  Write normal code in an if block.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 2 problems in your code.

1. You are defining lambda function, but not calling it. Expected expression type is boolean, but you have some (also not properly defined) functional interface in true part of your ternary operator. Correct version might look like this (note extra braces after lambda expression):

```
    boolean m = kara.treeFront() ? (()-> {
            //content of function
            return true;
            })() : false;
```

2. Java is strictly typed language and so are lambda expressions. They must be (implicitly or explicitly) of some functional interface type. Normally compiler can extract type information from context, but in this case it is `boolean` type expected, not an interface. I'm not sure how smart compiler is on guessing lambda interface, but here it will likely fail. So, you'll probably need your lambda interface to be explicitly declared (`Supplier<Boolean>`, for example).